# Toggle an Amazon Smart Plug from a Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, iot, alexa-skills-kit

I have an "Amazon Smart Plug" connected to home WiFi, and it is controllable right now using two mechanisms:

- From my Echo Show device, I can turn the plug on and off using the touchscreen or Alexa voice control.
- Using the Alexa app on mobile devices, I can turn the plug on and off.

I would like to add a third way to turn the plug on and off, and that third mechanism calls a Lambda function.

So, I need an API that allows me to do the appropriate authentication, and then be able to do something like this via Lambda:

1. Enumerate the devices connected to my Alexa account.
2. Find the device I'm interested in by its friendly name or underlying ID/serial.
3. Get the current status of the plug (powered on or powered off).
4. If it's off, turn it on; if it's on, turn it off.

Does such an API exist? I know there are similar APIs for LIFX devices and so on, but these are directly connected Amazon Smart Plugs that only integrate with Alexa itself and Echo devices.

I just need a pointer to the relevant API, as there are a lot of APIs out there for things I'm *not* looking for that seem to obscure the Google results, like the Alexa Skills API which is for designing new capabilities into the voice assistant -- not what I'm going for. I can figure out the code once I find the right API.